# How to show that if $\inf A > - \infty$ and $\inf B > - \infty, A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ then $A+B = \{a+b:a \in A, b \in B \}$ is bounded below?

Tags: measure-theory

How to show that if $\inf A > - \infty$ and $\inf B > - \infty$, $A,\, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ then $A+B = \left\{a+b:a \in , b \in B \right\}$ is bounded below?

Comment: ... bounded from below?

Comment: What would be the most obvious bound from below you might think of?

Comment: If $inf A = a$ and $inf B = b$, then $a \leq x, \forall x \in A$ and $b \leq x, \forall x \in B$ so bound from below for $C=A+B$ is a+b, which satisfies $a+b \leq x, \forall x \in C$

Comment: How is this measure theory?

Comment: They use $inf A$ for measure $m_n$

Comment: I suppose that $A+B=A \cup B$? But I don't understand how do you then get that below bound is a+b? So is first equivalence true?

Comment: @alvoutila. $A+B:=\{a+b:a\in A\,\,\mathrm{and}\,\,b\in B\}$, which is not necessarily $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $m_A=\inf{A},\;\; m_B=\inf{B}.$ Then 
\begin{gather}
\forall{a}\in{A} & {a}\geqslant{m_A} \\
\forall{b}\in{B} & {b}\geqslant{m_B}
\end{gather}
So, 
\begin{gather}
(\forall{a}\in{A})(\forall{b}\in{B}) \\
{a+b}\geqslant{m_A+m_B}
\end{gather}

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $\inf A+\inf B\leq A+B$. Since the left is a lower bound, we have $\inf A+\inf B\leq\inf (A+B)$.